# Why does this belong on SO and not Serverfault or Superuser?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, migration, declined-flags

### What am I missing here?

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920250/need-to-add-50-users-with-specific-uid-range-identified-userid-list-custom-use) to have it moved because, to me, this clearly looked like a sysadmin issue, and didn't fall into any of these categories (per the help center):

- *a specific programming problem*, You could answer this without programming; it relates to adding users. Tools exist for this purpose. Including bulk-provisioning tools; or
- *a software algorithm*, The user isn't asking about the algorithm, just the syntax; or
- *software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
  a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*, Not unique to software development, and I'd argue that "useradd" is a program which, if the sysadmin is doing their job, the dev need never run. Which isn't to say I haven't run it myself, but not in my capacity as a programmer

I suppose the software argument could be made because there is a programming language involved, but bash is a glue language and I know plenty of people who can write bash scripts but wouldn't call themselves programmers. What really sealed the deal for me is that the OP actually said "I am using centOS in an administration class," within which the question came up. If that doesn't say "sysadmin question" I don't know what does.

As a rule, I flag things pretty rarely. Only when something clearly seems like a bad fit.

Comment: I'm not impressed by your deleted comment about getting a moderator stupid enough to say there was no evidence to support your migration request.  I'm also not particularly impressed that you thought the issue was important enough to raise once again here.

Comment: That a question may be a better fit on another site doesn't automatically make it off-topic. If it is reasonably on-topic, why move it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, the reason provided for denying the migration request was so cursory and unhelpful that I admit I took it as an insult. While I freely admit my reaction was less than polite, the purpose was not to impress you; it was to shame the original person into providing more helpful feedback. Since shame is an approved motivational tool on SO (hence the entire voting system), I didn't see the ideological issue, there.

Comment: Voting is a feedback mechanism, not a shaming tool.  If you think votes are about a pat on the back or a kick in the groin, you've entirely missed the point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I asked the question here because the explanation from the original reviewer failed to be explanatory, so I had to turn to the larger community. On the one hand, I'm sorry you aren't impressed, but on the other I wasn't really trying to impress you.

Comment: I don't require your approval, never did. But you don't have to be a clod either.  The community runs on professionalism, not mud slinging.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's a feedback mechanism used to condition the behavior of humans on the internet. If it doesn't elicit an emotional response, it won't work.

Comment: Going from that to calling it an "approved shaming tool" is a really big stretch.

Comment: "But you don't have to be a clod either" Gentlemen, we have irony.

Comment: If the shoe fits...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I won't make another comment in that vein. It wasn't my best moment. But I do defend this question. Because I didn't know the answer before I asked it, and now I do.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, yes. I thought the shoe fit, too. But I'm glad you apply exceptionalism to yourself at the expense of your ethical high ground.

Comment: @ParthianShot _the reason provided for denying the migration request was so cursory and unhelpful_ - you received a pre-defined response for a flag which was "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".  I'm not sure why you were insulted by this, it is pretty self-explanatory. We reviewed the flag but didn't agree.

Comment: The moderators at Stack Overflow are not exceptional in any way, except that they've voluntarily chosen to give of their precious free time to clean up other people's messes.  Regardless of what you think of me or any of the other moderators, if you cannot afford them a minimal amount of respect as people, at least you can try to respect their time.

Comment: @bluefeet As the accepted answer mentions, "One could argue either way there". So the response "found no evidence" feels like a bit of a slap in the face. If the person had given an explanation of "it fits better here because X", that would have been more helpful. Are all of the responses menu items, or is there a way to provide a free response?

Comment: @ParthianShot Yes, we can add a custom message and we use it when it warrants it.  In this case, it didn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I respect the time and the people. Despite the fact that we disagree, you seem like an alright guy. But it also takes time to determine questions need flagging and flag them. Regardless of what you think of me, I am also donating my time to improve the site. If you cannot afford me a minimal amount of respect as a person, at least you can try to respect my time.

Comment: @bluefeet Mine is clearly the minority opinion on that, then. Which is also a good thing to know. Thank you.

Comment: @Will You haven't participated in a single [tag:bash] question (for example) and very few [tag:linux] or [tag:scripting], and that's fair enough. However, is the fact that *you* are not interested in such questions a good reason to prevent others from asking and answering them? Yes, a number of these questions will be borderline between programming and sysadmin, but you can simply ignore them like you would ignore other questions on other tags or subjects you don't normally follow.

Comment: @bruno: I doubt that Will was [being serious](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3568876d79f0551ec5d77652eb8ae9ef?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG).

Comment: @Bruno you don't need to be a l337 unix haxorz to know that a batch script can only tenuously be called "programming."  And they suck, and should be all closed and deleted.  Yeah, I went there, but you forced my hand.  Be it on your head.

Comment: @Will ...Okay, to clarify, I do Not Agree(TM) with this sentiment. Although I will agree that [real programmers don't use Pascal](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/real.programmers.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We tend only to migrate when it is extremely clear that the target site is wholly appropriate, and the existing site is not. One could argue either way there, so I can see it being left. If the question was more about using some 'tool' to accomplish the task, or less about the scripting, then it might have been more appropriate elsewhere.

And kudos for wanting to improve your flagging, by the way.

<sup>Incidentally, your comment there about the moderation response was less than polite</sup>

Comment: There were also no votes to close the question to move it to SF, so no other users thought that this possibly was a better fit for another site or was off-topic for SO.

Comment: +1 for not trying to close this question purely based on its application domain. Some people seem to be simply allergic to questions that invlove any sysadmin stuff.

Comment: @bluefeet [I don't see the relevance, there.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) Are you saying that there haven't been questions closed or moved with one vote to close or move, or that those questions which were moved/closed with one vote were moved/closed in error? [Or that I'm the god who always lies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hardest_Logic_Puzzle_Ever)?

Comment: @ParthianShot I'm saying that I also take into consideration feedback from the community when making decisions.  When your flag was reviewed, there was an answer, no close votes, etc plus the question appears to be on-topic for SO - I take all of these things into account.

Comment: @bluefeet That's fair. And I didn't know it was you when I responded the way I did. I'm actually quite fond of your writing style, posts and comments. Sorry about the rudeness.

Comment: I can think of _five_ different SE sites that a question like this may be on-topic on. I generally wouldn't think about migrating unless the site it was posted to was blatantly off-topic, or sometimes, if I thought the user would not get a good answer on the site it was originally posted on, and would be much more likely to get a good answer on another site.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Now, if someone had flagged to move it to [Cooking.SE], I know I'd have done it! ;)